# KVM Virgl acceleration only works on some guests?

Tags: kvm, graphics, opengl

I'm using the following graphics settings for my KVM guests:

```
...
<graphics type="spice">
  <listen type="none"/>
  <image compression="off"/>
  <gl enable="yes" rendernode="/dev/dri/by-path/pci-0000:69:00.0-render"/>
</graphics>
...
<video>
  <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes">
    <acceleration accel3d="yes"/>
  </model>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</video>
...
```

Which is working perfectly fine for Fedora (32/33) and Ubuntu (20.04), but I couldn't make it work on any other distro so far. Even on Fedora, it only works if you turn it on (`enable="yes"`) after installing (won't work on the live cd). But after that, it works out of the box.

When trying the same on - let's say - manjaro, even the `grub` menu freezes and is unusable. I tried `systemd-boot` instead as well. However, if you manage to boot it, the screen will remain black (it appears to be running just fine, as the mouse integration is working despite the black screen).

**Update:**
It doesn't seem to be a kernel issue after all. I missed this as I had autologin enabled, but lightdm shows up just fine. It's actually the DE (XFCE) that is giving me a black screen. Gnome on Wayland and Xorg works fine. The GRUB menu is still unusable though. It seems to just be a virgl compatibility issue with GRUB? and XFCE. I might try again without EFI, but the original issue is basically resolved.

<s>Now I wonder: What does fedora/ubuntu have that e.g.: manjaro is missing? Is it a kernel option or some driver package that I'm missing?</s>

I tried installing `virglrenderer` on my manjaro guest, which didn't help (I'm not sure if it's meant for the guest either).

**Update:**

When using ssh on the manjaro guest with a black screen, I get:

```
dmesg | grep drm
[    0.836414] [drm] pci: virtio-vga detected at 0000:00:01.0
[    0.836420] fb0: switching to virtiodrmfb from EFI VGA
[    0.836526] [drm] virgl 3d acceleration enabled
[    0.836527] [drm] EDID support available.
[    0.837182] [drm] number of scanouts: 1
[    0.837186] [drm] number of cap sets: 2
[    0.845823] [drm] cap set 0: id 1, max-version 1, max-size 308
[    0.845964] [drm] cap set 1: id 2, max-version 2, max-size 688
[    0.846341] [drm] Initialized virtio_gpu 0.1.0 0 for virtio0 on minor 0
[    0.848777] virtio_gpu virtio0: fb0: virtio_gpudrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.095162] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
```

And the working fedora guest:

```
dmesg | grep drm
[    2.164964] [drm] pci: virtio-vga detected at 0000:00:01.0
[    2.177043] [drm] features: +virgl +edid
[    2.177652] [drm] number of scanouts: 1
[    2.177658] [drm] number of cap sets: 2
[    2.193509] [drm] cap set 0: id 1, max-version 1, max-size 308
[    2.193596] [drm] cap set 1: id 2, max-version 2, max-size 688
[    2.193840] [drm] Initialized virtio_gpu 0.1.0 0 for virtio0 on minor 0
[    2.217427] virtio_gpu virtio0: [drm] fb0: virtio_gpudrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.552834] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
```

And on the host (working vm has the same output, but works):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/edk2/ovmf/OVMF_CODE.fd \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/path/to/qemu/nvram/manjaro_VARS.fd \
-drive file=/path/to/manjaro.qcow2 \
-m 8192 -enable-kvm -M q35 -cpu host -smp 16,sockets=1,cores=16,threads=1 \
-vga virtio -display gtk,gl=on \
-usb -device usb-tablet \
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 -net nic

gl_version 46 - core profile enabled
vrend_renderer_fill_caps: Entering with stale GL error: 1280
GLSL feature level 430
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Xfwm's built-in compositor and virgl don't play nice together.

Work-around: Boot the VM with virgl=off (on the video device) or gl=off (on the display), run xfwm4-tweaks-settings in the VM, select the "Compositor" tab, and uncheck "Enable display compositing".  Then shut down the VM and re-enable virgl.

picom works with Xfwm and doesn't seem to have the same issues, so if you want a compositor, install/use picom in the VM instead of using Xfwm's built-in compositor: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Picom

Comment: can't believe this actually worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This is just an overview of *what and how well it works* - I don't know why it is that way atm.

A Manjaro guest can work with virgl, it seems to be XFCE that is having issues with it. E.g. Gnome on Wayland or X works.

I did install `spice-gtk` and `qemu-guest-agent` on the Manjaro guest. (I haven't checked if they were responsible for making it work.)

However, despite the graphical vt being responsive, when switching to a console tty, it's extremely unresponsive (this is also true for Fedora).